# How to build a widget which launches an android application?

Tags: android, android-widget, launch

I have built a custom android application for Galaxy Note.

Is there a way to launch the application through a large widget which takes up approximately full size of the screen ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this -

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
try
{
    String packageName = "com.example.package";
    Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
catch (Exception e1)
{
}
```